# Update google spreadsheet automatically when a new file is added to google drive

Tags: database, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, new-operator, updating

I need to get a google spreadsheet sheet updated when a new file gets added to a certain google drive folder.

It needs to pull data such as 'name', 'date' and 'url link'.

I've read somehwere that google sheet scripts won't let you add "new file" as event, so I will have to run it every 30 minutes, theres no issue with that;
What I can't do is clear the spreadsheet and create a new one, since the content is a lot and it takes around 10 minutes to fill the spreadsheet with all the data from google drive.

This is the script I've used to create the spreadsheet

```
function listFolders(folder) {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Sharing Access", "Sharing Permission", "Get Editors", "Get Viewers", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Type"]); //writes the headers
     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("YOUR_FOLDER_ID");//that long chunk of random numbers/letters in the URL when you navigate to the folder

     var files = folder.getFiles();//initial loop on loose files w/in the folder

     var cnt = 0;
     var file;

     while (files.hasNext()) {
         var file = files.next();
         var listEditors = file.getEditors(); //gets the editor email(s), doesn't show your own as it's assumed
         var editors = [];
         for (var cnt = 0; cnt < listEditors.length; cnt++) {
             editors.push(listEditors[cnt].getEmail());
             Logger.log(editors);
         };
         var listViewers = file.getViewers(); //gets the viewer email(s)
         var viewers = [];
         for (var cnt = 0; cnt < listViewers.length; cnt++) {
             viewers.push(listViewers[cnt].getEmail());
             Logger.log(viewers);
         }
         cnt++;  //data chunk pushes all the file info to the ss

         data = [
             file.getName(),
             file.getSharingAccess(),
             file.getSharingPermission(),
             editors.toString(),
             viewers.toString(),
             file.getDateCreated(),
             file.getSize(),
             file.getUrl(),
             "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
             file.getDescription(),
             file.getMimeType(),
         ];

         sheet.appendRow(data);

     };


     var subfolders = folder.getFolders(); //same thing as above but for all the subfolders in the folder

     while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
         //Logger.log(folder);
         var name = subfolders.next();

         var files = name.getFiles();

         var cnt = 0;
         var file;

         while (files.hasNext()) {
             var file = files.next();
             var listEditors = file.getEditors();
             var editors = [];
             for (var cnt = 0; cnt < listEditors.length; cnt++) {
                 editors.push(listEditors[cnt].getEmail());
                 Logger.log(editors);
             };
             var listViewers = file.getViewers();
             var viewers = [];
             for (var cnt = 0; cnt < listViewers.length; cnt++) {
                 viewers.push(listViewers[cnt].getEmail());
                 Logger.log(viewers);
             }
             cnt++;

             data = [
                 file.getName(),
                 file.getSharingAccess(),
                 file.getSharingPermission(),
                 editors.toString(),
                 viewers.toString(),
                 file.getDateCreated(),
                 file.getSize(),
                 file.getUrl(),
                 "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
                 file.getDescription(),
                 file.getMimeType(),
             ];
             sheet.appendRow(data);
         };
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Rubén how to update google spreadsheet automatically when a new file is added to google drive?

Comment: Use a time-driven trigger to call a script that search for files created since the last time it was ran.

Comment: @theotherday Welcome. Each file has a unique `fileID`. Why not add the ID to the data that you retrieve and push to the "data array". Then get the `fileID` column from your spreadsheet, loop though the ID doing `indexof` and identify the files that "aren't' matched; then you only have to add those files to the spreadsheet. On the other hand, I note that you record a LOT of information about each file, so even if a file isn't new that file might have changed some parameters. If that's the case, then you need to loop through each row and compare the existing values to the value in the array.

Comment: Doh. At present you copy every single file to your target sheet; a better alternative is to first get the `getLastUpdated` value; if that is older than, say, one hour, then you can afford to skip that file and move onto the next file because it will already be on your spreadsheet. That would save an enormous amount of time. if the `getLastUpdated value is less than one hour, then get the `fileID` row from the spreadsheet, and just update that row. FWIW, you can make an "audit" report to compare the count of files in each folder to the number of files on the spreadsheet - they should agree.